# Linq to SQL Where Extension Method Question

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The Linq to SQL Where extension method takes, as a parameter, something that looks like this:

```
Expression<Func<Table,bool>> predicate
```

Could someone describe, in simple terms, exactly what this statement means? I want to create a method that takes one of these, that I can pass onto an L2S query, and I want to understand exactly what it is, and how it should be called.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable type `Expression<Func<Table, bool>>` means it takes a code expression representing a method/delegate/lambda expression that takes a `Table` parameter and returns a `bool`.  A method that takes an `Expression<>` parameter intends to parse the code to generate other code rather than evaluating the `Expression` itself.  LINQ to SQL can use them to generate SQL code to do what your code represents.

The strange thing about `Expression<>` parameters is that you pass values into them the same way that you'd pass a lambda expression, but whether your value is interpreted as an `Expression` or a lambda depends on the signature of the method you're passing it into.

Here's an example of passing an `Expression<Func<Table, bool>>` into a method (which looks the same as passing a `Func<Table, bool>` parameter:

```
theMethod(table => table.NumLegs > 3);

// or to be more explicit:
theMethod((Table table) => table.NumLegs > 3);

// or...
theMethod(delegate(Table table) { return table.NumLegs > 3; } );
```

Here's how you'd write your own method that takes one as a parameter and applies it to a L2S query:

```
IQueryable<Table> addWhereClause(
    IQueryable<Table> tables, Expression<Func<Table, bool>> whereClause)
{
    return tables.Where(whereClause);
}
```

Comment: Excellent work. If I could vote you up more than once, I would do so.

Answer (score 1):

I am just providing a simple explanation for how expressions work.From the sample code in the example given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710.aspx) is an example -

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = i => i < 5;
// Compile the expression tree into executable code.
Func<int, bool> deleg2 = expr.Compile();
// Invoke the method and print the output.
Console.WriteLine("deleg2(4) = {0}", deleg2(4));
//OUTPUT : deleg2(4) = True
```

So in simple words say you have a function that returns true if no < 5 like -

```
Func<int, bool> deleg = i => i < 5;
```

So you can build an expression doing same thing using above syntax and then pass it to say 
a `Where` or some thing simliar.Simple example -

```
int[] i={1,2,3,4,5} 
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = i => i < 5;
 var result=i.Where(expr);//equivalent to i.Where(c=>c<5)
```

In your case you have a table as the parameter so it will take an table object and return bool.

```
List<Employee> e= new List<Employee>();
   e.Add(new Employee(1,"ABC",5000));
   e.Add(new Employee(2,"ACC",5000));
   e.Add(new Employee(3,"ADC",50009));
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Employee, bool>> expr =e => e.Salary < 50000;
     var result=e.Where(expr);//give all employee with salary<50000
```